# What is the easy way to open a template .xls and write in at 2 cells?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, ms-office, xls

I have a template for excel and i want to open and write in sheet2 two things in 2 different cells. I search on the internet but have some things in code where i don't need, if i try to clean that code get me error. I want a easy way write in Excel and save him.

Answer (score 2):

If you need handle with POCO, you can use my tool [Npoi.Mapper](https://github.com/donnytian/Npoi.Mapper). It's also based on NPOI.
C# code like below, but you can easily convert to VB.NET:

```
var mapper = new Mapper("Book1.xlsx");
mapper.Put(products, "sheet1", true/*overwrite existing rows*/);
mapper.Put(orders, "sheet2", false/*append rows*/);
mapper.Save("Book1.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

*"I want a easy way write in Excel and save him"*

You could use **[NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/releases)** library, also this way you can avoid tedious *Microsoft Office* dependencies for `Excel` interop.

A short home-made example:

```
Imports NPOI
Imports NPOI.HSSF.UserModel
Imports NPOI.HSSF.Util
Imports NPOI.SS.UserModel
Imports NPOI.SS.UserModel.Charts
Imports NPOI.SS.Util
Imports NPOI.XSSF.UserModel

Dim WorkBookFile As String = "C:\MyWorkBook.xlsx"

' Create the excel workbook instance.
Dim workbook As IWorkbook = Nothing

' Load the workbook.
Using file As New FileStream(WorkBookFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    workbook = New XSSFWorkbook(file)
End Using

' Get the first sheet.
Dim sheet As ISheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0)

' Get the first row.
Dim row As IRow = sheet.GetRow(0)

' Create a cell.
Dim cell As ICell = row.CreateCell(1)

' Get the cell value.
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.StringCellValue) Then ' If value is emty then...

 Set cell value.
    cell.SetCellValue("This is a test")

End If

' Save changes.
Using sw As FileStream = File.Create(WorkBookFile)
    workbook.Write(sw)
End Using
```

see their **[Documentation](https://npoi.codeplex.com/documentation)** for official getting started examples.